# Azure Devops Pipeline PowerShell@2 task- performance degradation

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Since yesterday I noticed a significant performance degradation in executing some tasks in my pipeline that run PowerShell scripts, something that used to take a second or less now takes about 30 seconds.

No changes were made to the script within the task, and looking at the timeline from the logs the script executes at the same speed as before, what's seems to be taking longer is loading the task itself.

See the time it takes in the log below to the 'Generating script'

```
2023-09-22T11:37:41.8526876Z ##[section]Starting: Get latest build id
2023-09-22T11:37:41.8656716Z ==============================================================================
2023-09-22T11:37:41.8656891Z Task         : PowerShell
2023-09-22T11:37:41.8656960Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
2023-09-22T11:37:41.8657094Z Version      : 2.228.0
2023-09-22T11:37:41.8657162Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-09-22T11:37:41.8657247Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
2023-09-22T11:37:41.8657393Z ==============================================================================
2023-09-22T11:38:19.5788471Z Generating script.
2023-09-22T11:38:21.4712306Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2023-09-22T11:38:21.4999099Z ##[command]"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\29d29486-b5d7-4487-be00-e0187e860ff8.ps1'"
2023-09-22T11:38:29.5517463Z Resolve PAT
2023-09-22T11:38:32.0041258Z Get definitionid
2023-09-22T11:38:32.0048080Z https://dev.azure.com/mycompany/myapp/_apis/build/definitions?name=CreditReference&api-version=7.1-preview.7
2023-09-22T11:38:56.9989185Z definitionId: 9668
2023-09-22T11:38:57.0015076Z https://dev.azure.com/mycompany/myapp/_apis/build/builds?definitions=9668&resultFilter=succeeded&api-version=7.1-preview.7
2023-09-22T11:38:57.9464070Z Found 1 versions
2023-09-22T11:38:57.9544224Z 245699 - 4/21/2023 8:20:05 AM
2023-09-22T11:39:02.8780176Z ##[section]Finishing: Get latest build id
```

And compare this to the one from a couple of days ago:

```
2023-09-20T11:03:43.2781737Z ##[section]Starting: Get latest build id
2023-09-20T11:03:43.3036843Z ==============================================================================
2023-09-20T11:03:43.3036985Z Task         : PowerShell
2023-09-20T11:03:43.3037045Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
2023-09-20T11:03:43.3037135Z Version      : 2.226.2
2023-09-20T11:03:43.3037189Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-09-20T11:03:43.3037261Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
2023-09-20T11:03:43.3037360Z ==============================================================================
2023-09-20T11:03:45.1817132Z Generating script.
```

BTW, changing the script to execute with Powershell Core instead of Powershell has improved slightly the time it takes to execute but is still significantly slower.

What I have noticed is that the version of the PowerShell@2 has changed from 2.226.2 two days ago to 2.228.0.

Is there a way I can specify which version of PowerShell@2 to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose specific version in the task

```
steps:

- task: PowerShell@2.226.2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.
      
      Get-Host
```

[image]

Comment: That's very useful. Unfortunately it turns out that rolling back the version is not restoring the previous performance so I will need to investigate this further, but your answer allowed me to experiment with this, thanks!

Comment: @techromancer did you find a solution to this? I'm experiencing the same issues, taking over a minute on the "generate" portion of a pretty simple powershell script.

Comment: Yes, I logged the issue with MS and they fixed it - ticket: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-Devops-Pipeline-PowerShell2-task-/10473639?stateGroup=closed&q=powershell&sort=newest&page=1